# How to really ensure files can be opened?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I know there are quite a few questions that may sound similar, but they never cover my needs, so here's my own attempt:

I am pretty aware, that I can fetch the UTI of a file and use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to either check if there's at least one app that can open it or ask the user to select an app, that's great.

Also the `UIWebView` can open a bunch of other UTIs as well, although it never tells the system what kind of and therefore never appears in the app selection dialog. So when I am sure there is no app I can still check if the `UIWebView` supports it and create an own view.

That works well to some degrees, until smartass apps like Dropbox appear and basically tell the system **I can open every UTI!**.

What now? For me that renders the whole mechanism kind of useless, I cannot use the fallback anymore and my only way is to let my app go the Dropbox-way and register every UTI as well.

Any ideas how to solve that?